# React router browser back button isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a multi step form using React JS and react-router.

The form step is changed with state. If I click on the button next the state step is incremented and the next step is shown.

But this way if I'm on for example third step and I click on the back in the browser I'm redirected to the home page instead of a previous step.

My main component is something like this :

```
componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props.params.id);
}

onButtonClick(name, event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    switch (name) {
        case "stepFourConfirmation":
            if(this.validation("four")) {
                this.props.actions.userRegistrationThunk(this.state.user);
                this.setState({step: 5, user: {}});
            }
            break;
        case "stepTwoNext":
            if(this.validation("two")) {
                this.setState({step: 3});
                this.context.router.push("stepThree");
            }
            break;
        case "stepThreeFinish":
            this.setState({step: 4});
            break;
        default:
            if(this.validation("one")) {
                this.setState({step: 2});
                this.context.router.push('stepTwo');
            }
    }
}
```

On every button click I push the parameter to the url and change the step. When I click next it's working perfect. In componentWillMount I'm trying to get the parameter from the url and I would than decrement the step depending on the parameter.

But only when the first step is loaded I se stepOne in the console. If I click on next I get *[react-router] Location "stepTwo" did not match any routes*

My routes.js file is as follows :

```
    import React from 'react';
import {IndexRoute, Route} from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import Registration from './components/registration/RegistrationPage';

import UserPage from './components/user/userHome';
import requireAuth from './common/highOrderComponents/requireAuth';
import hideIfLoggedIn from './common/highOrderComponents/hideIfLoggedIn';

import PasswordReset from './common/passwordReset';

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="registration/:id" component={hideIfLoggedIn(Registration)}/>
        <Route path="reset-password" component={PasswordReset} />
        <Route path="portal" component={requireAuth(UserPage)} />
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Any advice how to solve it?

Comment: can you provide a gist

Comment: With all my code? With components for each form step?

Comment: at least main component. more relevant info is better

Comment: Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/Borisboky/b90b1a338ac9cfc5ba484d5aa1e11c3d)

Comment: Have you tried `browserHistory.push(<your-route>)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try pushing an absolute path. Instead of

```
this.context.router.push("stepTwo");
```

try

```
this.context.router.push("/registration/stepTwo");
```

Additionally you have a problem with your lifecycle methods. componentWillMount is only called once. When you push the next route, the component is not mounted again, so you don't see the log with the next param. Use componentWillMount for the initial log, componentWillReceiveProps for the next ones:

```
componentWillMount() {
  console.log(this.props.params.id);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps.params.id);
}
```

Btw: here is a [discussion on github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2829). The creators state, that react router is not supporting relative paths

Comment: When I push `/registration/stepTwo` I do not get any react-router error but the paramater in the console log is still stepOne, but it needs to be stepTwo.

Comment: Edited my answer including correct lifecycle methods

Comment: Great. It worked. But I now I have a problem when I refresh the page on the second step. I get _external.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <_

Comment: This is most probably not related to this issue. Perhaps you have some syntax error in your component like writing <<div instead of <div in the jsx for step two?

Comment: That is not for step two only. It doesn't matter on which step I refresh the page, I get this error. When my first step loads first time I see everything nice, but when I refresh a page, I get that error.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see any issue in your code leading to this kind of error. I would suggest you to open the developer console in your browser and check the first line of the file external.js. There seems to be the problem.

Comment: There is no a problem. But thanks anyway. I'm going to ask another question.